# I don't understand how to use printf correctly in this circumstance

Tags: c

This is code for an assignment in class currently, the question asks us to prompt the user for a number to find the lowest positive divisor for.

I keep getting the error:
warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]

while using this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int divisor;
    int dividend;

    divisor=2;

    printf("Enter a number to divide: ");
    scanf("%d", &dividend);

    while(divisor!=0)
    {
        divisor++;
    }

    printf("%s","The lowest positive divisor is: ",dividend);
}
```

I think i need to be using %s somewhere but I am new to c++ and don't quite understand what formatting changes should be made

Comment: This seems to be C code.

Comment: I don't fully understand the differences between the languages yet.

Comment: @ConnerMiller Safe to say that you rarely use `scanf` and `printf` in C++ (although it is legal to do so). The rest of your code is C as well.

Comment: Assuming you actually want to learn C++, then you should probably forget about `printf` and `scanf` and learn how input and output is done in C++.

Comment: C++ is more or less a superset of C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Nope.

Comment: @NeilButterworth more or less, maybe emphasis on less

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%s","The lowest positive divisor is: ",dividend);
```

You only have one format specifier specified in your string but you pass 2 variables to `printf`. You should specify the `dividend` specifier too:

```
printf("%s %d","The lowest positive divisor is: ",dividend);
```

Comment: Surely the `%s` is unnecessary, that seems to be a misunderstanding of the OP

Comment: @john Oh yeah definitely, I just wanted to keep as much intact as I could.

Answer (score 1):

Place the %s inline like:

```
 printf("The lowest positive divisor is: %s", dividend);
```

But in this case use %d because it's an integer:

```
printf("The lowest positive divisor is: %d", dividend);
```